# How can I display max column width and write into a file with max width in Python?

Tags: python, column-width, truncated

I am trying to display a column in full (containing tweet texts) in Python, but even if I use pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None), the output returns as truncated. The code below lets me display the maximum width, but what I want is to save the file as output with max column width. Any help is appreciated.

```
def display_text_max_col_width(df, width):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', width):
        print(df)

display_text_max_col_width(df["col"], 1000)

[tweets ending with ellipsis][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

any text can be truncated by doing

```
MAX = 80
print(text[:MAX])
```

So its quite easy that way.

EDIT From your comments. I could not see any picture you posted but here is my suggestion.

if you have a long string (lets take part of this question) as some long strings.

```
txt1 = """ I am trying to display a column in full (containing tweet texts) in Python, but even if I use pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None), the output returns as truncated. The code below lets me display the maximum width, but what I want is to save the file as output with max column width. Any help is appreciated. """

txt2 = """Thanks for your response. Indeed, I am trying to get an untruncated column, which contains text, and save it as an output file (e.g., csv) as such. The problem is, ('display.max_colwidth', None) doesn't give me untruncated text in the related column. – Kamil Yilmaz 2 days ago"""
```

you are saying this is truncating or wont work for you, but that does work for me.

```
>>> with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', None): print(pd.DataFrame([txt1,txt2]))                                                                                                                         ...
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0
0  I am trying to display a column in full (containing tweet texts) in Python, but even if I use pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None), the output returns as truncated. The code below lets me display the maximum width, but what I want is to save the file as output with max column width. Any help is appreciated.
1                                          Tanks for your response. Indeed, I am trying to get an untruncated column, which contains text, and save it as an output file (e.g., csv) as such. The problem is, ('display.max_colwidth', None) doesn't give me untruncated text in the related column. – Kamil Yilmaz 2 days ago
>>>
```

However I would not use this method of displaying anything. You have got to either format it your self by running down the rows and formatting each cell yourself. Or contend with some wackiness from unfiltered control characters that the tweets may contain.

you can iterate over that quite easy with the 1st method I suggested:

```
>>> _ = [print(line[:60]) for line in df[0]]
I am trying to display a column in full (containing tweet te
Tanks for your response. Indeed, I am trying to get an untru
```

you can use tabulate to format the data frame if you dont want to iterate over the data.

```
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> print(tabulate(df))
-  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  I am trying to display a column in full (containing tweet texts) in Python, but even if I use pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None), the output returns as truncated. The code below lets me display the maximum width, but what I want is to save the file as output with max column width. Any help is appreciated.
1  Tanks for your response. Indeed, I am trying to get an untruncated column, which contains text, and save it as an output file (e.g., csv) as such. The problem is, ('display.max_colwidth', None) doesn't give me untruncated text in the related column. – Kamil Yilmaz 2 days ago
-  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or use a combination of both methods. But I'm not a fan of Pandas output as it is more bothersome than its worth.

print will print to a file if you provide a fp to it.

```
>>> with open('/tmp/text', 'w') as fp:
...     [print(line[:150], file=fp) for line in df[0]]
...
[None, None]
>>> [print(line) for line in open('/tmp/text').readlines() ]
I am trying to display a column in full (containing tweet texts) in Python, but even if I use pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None), the output

Tanks for your response. Indeed, I am trying to get an untruncated column, which contains text, and save it as an output file (e.g., csv) as such. The
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed, I am trying to get an untruncated column, which contains text, and save it as an output file (e.g., csv) as such. The problem is, ('display.max_colwidth', None) doesn't give me untruncated text in the related column.

Comment: When you say 'save' I assumed you meant file and that is not affected by display. If you do `>>> d = ['kjasdhfkjashflkjasdhfklhjasdklfjhasdklfjhasdjhfajhfklsjhfjhlajhfkljshkljshfdsdkjhfasl']
>>> with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', None): print(pd.DataFrame(d))`  does that work for you. If so can you post the example to show your error?

Comment: Thank you. I added a photo above (please use the link to open it, as I am not allowed to post pics here yet). It shows how the text gets truncated in the end with ellipsis...I want to write the dataframe into a file without this truncation of the text. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I could not see any pic so i just edit my answer to further suggest what to do.  Good luck

Comment: Thank you Peter for your time, fp was a good idea. Solved my problem. The texts are not ending with ellipsis and I was able to write as such. Thanks again and Kind regards.